# snapcraft snap failing because python modules are missing

Tags: packaging, snap

I'm attempting to learn something of snap desktop packaging by repackaging unity-tweak-tool as a snap. I am finding the docs to be less than stellar, but so far I've got a snapcraft.yaml file that looks like this:

```
name: unity-tweak-tool
version: 1
summary: configuration tool for the Unity desktop environment
description: |
 Unity Tweak Tool is a settings manager for the Unity desktop.
 It provides users with a fast, simple and easy-to-use interface 
 with which to access many useful and little known features and settings 
 of the desktop environment that one may want to configure.

apps:
  unity-tweak-tool:
    command: $SNAP/usr/bin/unity-tweak-tool
    plugs: [unity7]
parts:
  unity-tweak-tool:
    plugin: python3
    source: git://github.com/Seth-Johnson/unity-tweak-tool.git
    source-type: git
    build-packages:
        - python3-distutils-extra
        - python3-all
        - python3-dbus
        - python-dev
    stage-packages:
        - gir1.2-glib-2.0
        - gir1.2-gtk-3.0
        - python3-xdg
        - python3-cairo
        - unity-webapps-service
```

However when I run `snapcraft snap` setup.py always fails because several python modules are missing:

```
  Running setup.py install for unity-tweak-tool ... error
    Complete output from command /home/sethj/projects/snappy-testing/parts/unity-tweak-tool/install/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-s6dwhgys-build/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-xxv1mi7p-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --home=/tmp/tmp2y5izah7:
    ERROR: Python module values not found
    ERROR: Python module apport not found
    ERROR: Python module apport.hookutils not found
    WARNING: syntax errors in notes/wizardry.py: Missing parentheses in call to 'print' (wizardry.py, line 9)
    ERROR: Python module dbus not found
    ERROR: Python module dbus.service not found
    ERROR: Python module dbus.mainloop.glib not found
```

(full output [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/16824557/))

I admit I'm not 100% sure I doing this properly, but as far as I can tell it should be building the packages listed under build-packages, which satisfy the build requirements for unity-tweak-tool.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Apparently, the problem is the tag `--single-version-externally-managed`, there is evidence that may be old version of pip, as reported here: https://github.com/platformio/platformio/issues/279

Comment: @Elric Oh I see that error now. However I'm more worried about the python modules not being found, at the moment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the case of python you probably want some of those `build-packages` to be `stage-packages`. The python plugin sets `PYTHONPATH` to be within the snap which is why it's missing these packages (you have them installed on the host system instead).

Byt the way, if this upstream had a proper `install_requires` in `setup.py` these dependencies would have been taken care automatically for you.

Comment: Yup, this was my issue. Now that I think about it differently it makes sense that the packages would need to be under stage-packages instead of build-packages. Thanks!